# How to place buttons in the same line, center, and not too close to each other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 buttons :

- Download
- Edit

I want to place both of them in same line, side by side, but not too far away from each other either.

As of right now this what I have

[image]

I try to give them class `pull-left` and `pull-right`
This what they come out to be

[image]

They're too far away. :(

I want them to look something like this. 
Possible, with the vertical line in the middle.
I am not sure how to do that.

[image]

Here is my HTML Code

```
<p>
    <span>
        <a class="btn-1" href="/marketing_materials/{{$marketing_material->id}}/download/media_path">
            Download
        </a>
    </span>
</p>
<p>
    <span>
        <a class="btn-2" href="{{ URL::to('marketing_materials/'.$marketing_material->id.'/edit') }}">
            Edit
        </a>
    </span>
</p>
```

What should I do to get close to what I want ?

Comment: it seems like you are using a frame work such as foundation or bootstrap, please let us know what "pull" is.

Comment: I am sorry. I used `bootstrap` framework. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: The problem is that you have both in separate `p` tags (and p tags are displayed as block elements). Try to put them in the same block tag (such as p or div) and give them a margin instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You had 2 `<p>` tags, combine them into 1.
- Place them in the same `<p>` tag so that they will be in same line as you wanted.
- Add `style="text-align:center;"` into your `<p>` tag.
- Add a bunch of `&nbsp;` between them to maintain the spaces
- For your **vertical pipeline**, just do this `&nbsp;|&nbsp;`

Try this

```
<p style="text-align:center;">
    <span>
        <a class="btn-1 pull" href="/marketing_materials/{{$marketing_material->id}}/download/media_path">
            Download
        </a>
    </span>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span>
        <a class="btn-2" href="{{ URL::to('marketing_materials/'.$marketing_material->id.'/edit') }}">
            Edit
        </a>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Precisely - Well answer ! :)

Comment: Oh god `&nbsp;` ... is this answer from 1999?

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ : I agree. that `&nbsp` is making your code is a bit ugly, but what is your suggestion for improvement ? :) You can Edit his, or if possible, leave your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give a class on your `<p>` Example: `<p class="some-name">`

Put `.some-name { display: inline-block; }` in your stylesheet.

I would also suggest using better semantics for creating buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `p` tags with a container, and then you can add `display: inline-block` and `margin`. **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qxwc8g98/)**

```
<div class="buttons">

    <p>
        <span>
            <a class="btn-1 pull" href="#">
                Download
            </a>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            <a class="btn-2" href="#">
                Edit
            </a>
        </span>
    </p>

</div>
```

CSS

```
div.buttons p {display: inline-block;}
div.buttons p:last-child {margin-left: 20px;}
```